# How to create nested models from API request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I've a Rails API and I've two models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category

  has_many :event_categories
  has_many :events, through: :event_categories

  attr_accessible :title, :description, :event_categories_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_categories

end
```

and

```
class EventCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :category

  attr_accessible :category_id, :event_id, :principal

  validates :event, :presence => true
  validates :category, :presence => true

  validates_uniqueness_of :event_id, :scope => :category_id

end
```

In a first moment, `EventCategory` didn't exist so I created Event resources sending params like `event[title]='event1', event[description] = 'blablbla'` thought POST REST request.

My API EventsController was like this (I haven't a new method because I don't need views):

```
 def create
    @event = Event.create(params[:event])
    if @event
      respond_with @event
    else
      respond_with nil, location: nil, status: 404
    end
  end
```

This way worked correctly for me. Now, with the new EventCategory model I don't know how I could create EventCategories models at the same time.

I've trying this... but it doesn't work:

```
  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
    @event.event_categories.build
    if @event.save
      respond_with @event
    else
      respond_with nil, location: nil, status: 404
    end
  end
```

Rails told me:

```
{
    "event_categories.event": [
        "can't be blank"
    ],
    "event_categories.category": [
        "can't be blank"
    ]
}
```

I send the `category_id` like this:

```
event[event_categories_attributes][0][category_id] = 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us your params hash?

Comment: (rdb:1) p params
{"event"=>{"title"=>"blabalb", "description"=>"mas baksldbadbnlas", "event_categories_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"category_id"=>"1"}}}, "access_token"=>"24cd498338b8f305dc925d9fba319ad05f258f1ec0869d676bb35fea9930ce8c", "format"=>"json", "a
ction"=>"create", "controller"=>"api/v1/events"}
(rdb:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `create` action, instead of this:

```
@event.event_categories.build
```

Try this:

```
@event.event_categories = EventCategory.new do |ec|
    ec.event = @event
    ec.category = the_cattegory_you_want_to_specify
    # You need both of these as you are validating the presence of event AND category
end
```